# jquery ajax to file:// not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I am trying to run a simple web page offline. Meaning I am launching the html page directly from my desktop without a server. Firefox & Safari are not giving me any trouble but IE is of course. IE versions 9+

I am using Jquery to do a Ajax call to a local json file and the damn ajax call are just not completing.

I have tried $.get, $.post, $.ajax, $.getJSON, $("body").load(), but none work.

I have also tried different urls 
file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.json
C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.json
C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.json

I tried different Jquery version too 1.8.3, 1.11.3, 2.1.3

I have simplified it to bare bones

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $.get("file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/file.json", function(data){
        console.log(data);
     }).done(function(){
        alert("done");    
     }).fail(function(){
        alert("fail");
     });
});
```

Comment: Ajax to a file protocol doesn't work in any browser ?

Answer (score 4):

That is blocked for security reasons, it is also blocked by chrome on default.
If you want to access a file please use a javascript upload script. Maybe this tutorial will help: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/